# In Python , find the minimum product of two integers in an array/list, assuming that all values in the array/list are non-negative?

Tags: arrays, list

Write a Python program that has the following methods:
Given an array or list of unsorted integers, find the minimum product of two integers in an array/list, assuming that all values in the array/list are non-negative. For example, if the arr = [6, 3, 8, 2, 9] then the minimum product would be = 6, as 2 and 3 are the smallest integers in this given array and hence their product will be the answer. To solve this problem, the following idea can be used:
Answer the following question:
a) One of the solutions is to : "Consider every pair in the given array and return the Minimum product.

Comment: This looks copy/pasted from a homework assignment, if this is the case I would urge you to give it a go yourself and then ask for help on getting your existing code to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sort the list and return the product of the first 2 elements in the sorted list.

```
def minProduct(list):
    sorted_list = list.sort()
    return sorted_list[0] * sorted_list[1]
```

I'm sure a faster method would be to specifically find the 2 smallest values in the list, but this is a nice simple way.

Comment: Thanks sir ,
but i want to ask .. how i add the values please

Comment: By add do you mean pass the values to the function? if so just call the function and pass the list in as the argument `minProduct([1,2,3,4,5])`